# Android Service Multiple Services opened

Tags: java, android, service, schedule, timertask

I'm doing a project where I have to do a sync every 10 sec, I take on the server what people want to sync. Save this preferences in a array and go around the array to see the user preferences (what they want to sync). If the id 1 is selected then do a log.i ();

This is giving me a problem: every time it syncs it does a log.i("Starting service"); + log.i ("Big sheet"). as time passes it is becoming this way:

2nd sync:
log.i("Starting service");
log.i("Big sheet!")
log.i("Big sheet!")

3rd sync:
log.i("Starting service");
log.i("Big sheet!")
log.i("Big sheet!")
log.i("Big sheet!")

...and every time the same, may I'm opening multiple services?

`public class service extends Service{`

```
Context context;
Timer t=new Timer();
timertask timertask=new timertask();
database db;
List checksync =new ArrayList();

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

public void onCreate(){
    //Se comienza aqui!
    super.onCreate();
    //Cojemos el contexto del thread de UI
    context=this;
    db=new database(context);
    onStartCommand1();
}

public void onStartCommand1(){
    //Tiempo de sincronización!
    t.schedule(timertask, 0,5000);
    this.stopSelf();
}

public class timertask extends TimerTask{

    public void run() {
        //Comenzamos a ver que està seleccionado y hacemos threads para subirlo al server

        int num=0;
        db.open();
        checksync = db.check();
        db.close();
        int lenght = checksync.size();
        check(lenght,num);
        Log.i("******", "Starting service");
    }

    public void check(int lenght, int num){

        for(int x=0; x < lenght; x++) {

            num = Integer.parseInt(checksync.get(x).toString());

            if (num == 1) {
                // Subir Sms al server.

            } else if (num == 2) {
                // Subir llamadas

            } else if (num == 3) {
                //subir contactos
                Log.i("*********", "Big sheet!");

            } else if (num == 4) {
                // Subir nombre apps

            } else if (num == 5) {
                // Subir localizaciÔøΩn.

            } else if (num == 6) {
                // Subir todo... (MÔøΩs tarde)
            }
        }
    }

}

public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

Comment: umm guys... do we have an official language on stackoverflow or everyone just uses it because it is convenient for everyone??

Comment: Several months ago I proposed to close questions that are not in English. I guess this can be the case (too narrow question).

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/